# ошибка при работе с картой

Tags: java, android, android-sdk, google-maps, android-bundle

В портретной ориентации все работает отлично но когда поворачиваю экран программа вылетает.

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/app_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/fragment_map_toolbar"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:elevation="4dp"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme"
            app:theme="@style/ToolbarTheme"/>


    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab_layers"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        app:useCompatPadding="true"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_info" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab_my_location"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="top|end"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_map_location"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/fab_layers"
        app:useCompatPadding="true"
        app:backgroundTint="@android:color/white"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="top" />

    <com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView
        android:id="@+id/fragment_map_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

***Код фрагмента:***

```
public class FragmentMap extends Fragment implements OnMapReadyCallback {
    private static final String TAG = "FragmentMap";

private FragmentWeatherMain.Callbacks mCallbacks;
private Toolbar mToolbar;
private MapView mMapView;

public static FragmentMap newInstance() {
    return new FragmentMap();
}

@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity){
    super.onAttach(activity);
    mCallbacks = (FragmentWeatherMain.Callbacks) activity;
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState){
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_map, container, false);
    getActivity().setTitle(String.format(getResources().getString(R.string.fragment_map_title)));

    mMapView = (MapView) view.findViewById(R.id.fragment_map_view);
    mMapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mMapView.getMapAsync(this);

    mToolbar = (Toolbar) view.findViewById(R.id.fragment_map_toolbar);
    ((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
    ((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    ((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
    mCallbacks.onDrawerToggleClick(mToolbar);

    return view;
}

@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    mMapView.onStart();
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    mMapView.onResume();
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    mMapView.onPause();
}

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        mMapView.onStop();
    }

    @Override
    public void onLowMemory() {
        super.onLowMemory();
        mMapView.onLowMemory();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        mMapView.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach(){
        super.onDetach();
        mCallbacks = null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        mMapView.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {

    }
}
```

***Ошибка:***

```
Class not found when unmarshalling: android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar$SavedState
                                                                           java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar$SavedState
                                                                               at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
                                                                               at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:324)
                                                                               at android.os.Parcel.readParcelableCreator(Parcel.java:2404)
                                                                               at android.os.Parcel.readParcelable(Parcel.java:2358)
                                                                               at android.os.Parcel.readValue(Parcel.java:2264)
                                                                               at android.os.Parcel.readSparseArrayInternal(Parcel.java:2675)
                                                                               at android.os.Parcel.readSparseArray(Parcel.java:1967)
                                                                               at android.os.Parcel.readValue(Parcel.java:2321)
                                                                               at android.os.Parcel.readArrayMapInternal(Parcel.java:2614)
                                                                               at android.os.BaseBundle.unparcel(BaseBundle.java:221)
                                                                               at android.os.Bundle.getBundle(Bundle.java:763)
                                                                               at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.ea.a(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesB:168)
                                                                               at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.impl.az.a(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesB:690)
                                                                               at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.impl.da.a(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesB:81)
                                                                               at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.z.onTransact(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesB:66)
                                                                               at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:387)
                                                                               at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.IMapViewDelegate$zza$zza.onCreate(Unknown Source)
                                                                               at com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView$zza.onCreate(Unknown Source)
                                                                               at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.zza$3.zzb(Unknown Source)
                                                                               at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.zza$1.zza(Unknown Source)
                                                                               at com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView$zzb.zzIL(Unknown Source)
                                                                               at com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView$zzb.zza(Unknown Source)
                                                                               at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.zza.zza(Unknown Source)
                                                                               at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.zza.onCreate(Unknown Source)
                                                                               at com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView.onCreate(Unknown Source)
                                                                               at com.example.jeka.exampledrawerbar.fragments.FragmentMap.onCreateView(FragmentMap.java:39)
                                                                               at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2087)
                                                                               at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1113)
                                                                               at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1295)
                                                                               at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1277)
                                                                               at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentManager.java:2154)
                                                                               at android.support.v4.app.FragmentController.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentController.java:201)
                                                                               at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:603)
                                                                               at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onStart(AppCompatActivity.java:181)
                                                                               at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1266)
                                                                               at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:6943)
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3276)
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3415)
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:5472)
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1200(ActivityThread.java:229)
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1827)
                                                                               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7325)
                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
                                                                            Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar$SavedState" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/data/com.google.android.gms/app_chimera/m/0000001b/DynamiteModulesB_GmsCore_prodmnc_xhdpi_release.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/user/0/com.google.android.gms/app_chimera/m/0000001b/n/armeabi-v7a, /data/user/0/com.google.android.gms/app_chimera/m/0000001b/n/armeabi, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
                                                                               at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
                                                                               at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
                                                                            at bzi.loadClass(:com.google.android.gms:34
```

Comment: Ошибок может быть очень много разных. Предлагаю не гадать и таки добавить логи ошибки и указать нам на какой строке она возникает

Comment: У вас что-то не так с тулбаром. Попробуйте все его упоминания временно выпилить из фрагмента.

Comment: пробовал, не помогает

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Попробуйте как [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38312686/3212712) советуют отделить при сохранении/восстановлении состояние карты от состояния фрагмента так:

```
// class property
private static final String KEY_MAP_SAVED_STATE = "mapState";

// class methods
@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    mapView = ...;
    Bundle mapState = (savedInstanceState != null)
            ? savedInstanceState.getBundle(KEY_MAP_SAVED_STATE): null;
    mapView.onCreate(mapState);
}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    Bundle mapState = new Bundle();
    mapView.onSaveInstanceState(mapState);
    outState.putBundle(KEY_MAP_SAVED_STATE, mapState);
}
```

Comment: спасибо, помогло